# Помогите подключить libhttpserver библиотеку

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

хочу разобраться с библиотекой
https://github.com/etr/libhttpserver
Помогите пожалуйста подключить ее к проекту на С++.
Создал в CLion чистый проект, сборка через CMake. Linux- Debian 12

Не могу понять из описания как это все установить.
Распишите по шагам что нужно сделать.

Уставновил бинарники выполнив команды:

```
sudo apt install libmicrohttpd-dev

./bootstrap
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

в папке "/usr/local/lib/" появились бинарники

[image: в папке "/usr/local/lib/" появились бинарники]

[image: includes]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvASU.png)

подскажите как подключить для билда бинарники в CMakeLists

Comment: Что именно вызывает трудности? Там вроде все стандартно: `make -> make install`, в `CMakeLists` `target_include_directories + target_link_libraries`.

Comment: я так понял нужно для установки библиотеки выполнить команды из раздела "Building" а потом прописать эту библиотеку в CMakeLists? Не нашел пример что прописать в CMakeLists

Comment: libmicrohttpd - это зависимость, ее нужно отдельно ставить?

Comment: Да, `libmicrohttpd` наверняка ставится из репозитория пакетным менеджером

Comment: помогите разобраться с CMakeLists